# объясните, как работает this

Tags: javascript

```
function delay(f, ms) {

  return function(...args) {
   let savedThis = this; // сохраняем this в промежуточную переменную
    setTimeout(function() {
      f.apply(savedThis, args); // используем её
    }, ms);
  };

}
```

1. почему, если в объявлении функции не сохранять this в промежуточную переменную, а просто использовать this = this от f, то в результате f = delay(f, ms) будет возвращать результат своего вызова без задержки в ms?
2. что за this мы вообще сохраняем в переменную, почему это не window.this?

Comment: А разве в книжках для новичков эта базовая информация (про this) не написана?

Comment: вот тут легко написано https://medium.com/@stasonmars/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-this-%D0%B2-javascript-a13b4b6ec9ac

Comment: Почитайте на [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods) или [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/companies/ruvds/articles/419371/